# Got the "My test app isn't responding right now. Try again soon." error message even a clean start from Google Assistant Simulator

Tags: firebase, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-home

I am still quite new to this topic, so sorry if I didn't provide enough information.

For the first time, I copoed everything from https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/first-app to learn about it, which works great.

After, I tried to create my own one, then at the end, I got this message "My test app isn't responding right now. Try again soon." from https://console.actions.google.com/project/[[PROJECT-ID]]/simulator/.

Therefore, I tried to delete everything and make a complete new start, including all the projects on https://console.actions.google.com/ and https://console.dialogflow.com.

I then copied the exact same thing from https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/first-app again, but this time, I still got "My test app isn't responding right now. Try again soon." from https://console.actions.google.com/project/[[PROJECT-ID]]/simulator/.

- I tried to look at firebase log, no error indeed
- I tried to use the `web demo` from the `integration` tab, everything works (which means the server side code or the connection have no problem) as expected, firebase also logged the request.
- I tried to use a different browser (chrome -> firefox) still not working.

Here is the response code from the Google Assistant Simulator (its kinda nothing):

```
{
  "audioResponse": "//NExAARqQ...",
  "conversationToken": "GidzaW11bG...",
  "response": "My test app isn't responding right now. Try again soon.",
  "visualResponse": {
    "visualElements": []
  }
}
```

And here is the debug message (yes, its nothing in there, so I'm stuck):

```
{
  "agentToAssistantDebug": {},
  "assistantToAgentDebug": {}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just a hint to check.Intents are working in the "try it now" section ?Integrations->Google Assistant->Settings->
Update Draft.At actions on google console->Test draft.
Sometimes it takes some time to update.

Comment: Yep, I did it already. "Actions on Google draft successfully updated" and "**Test now active** View on the Actions on Google Web Simulator or any Actions on Google enabled devices you are signed in to" but still have the same error (I actually did it when everything finished from the tutorial, I just did it again and will see)

Answer (score 2):

In Actions Console..

- Go to Develop -> Invocation
- Set a display name (Eg: Hello World) and click Save
- Go to Test and type "Talk to Hello World"

Fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Actions on Google project has a name.

Answer (score 0):

I spent almost 2 days scratching my head on this. Just go to [Activity controls](https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols) of the relevant google account (The account that you are using for the simulator) and turn on all those switches (You may leave out Youtube related stuff).

And.....Voila, it works!

Usually, these are turned off for non-personal accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue when I tried to change the language of app to a locale.

Try the following,

- Check if the welcome intent and fallback intents have responses and training phrases
- All contexts are mapped
- Disable and enable testing

Answer (score 0):

At least in my case, I've added 'Suggestions' for an ending scene, like below:

[image]

You can see the error on the right side log of 'Test' page:

[image]

Fix is to remove 'Suggestions' in ending scene.

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same issue and after struggling for hours I found the stupid error on my side: In my Dialogflow Agent settings, I accidentally turned on the V2 API. So my firebase function kept complaining about null intent.  Hope this help.

Comment: I just checked, but the v2 API was never turned on (Just in case a UI bug, I turned it on and off again to make sure it's 100% off), The error still exist, thanks anyways!