# Web Simulator showing "My Test App isn't responding right now. Try again soon" when I run "Talk to My Test App"

Tags: firebase, simulator, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I started a new new app with actions on google and when I run the simulator I'm receiving this message "My Test App isn't responding right now. Try again soon".

I am using firebase to deploy my fulfilment which looks like this

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const App = require("actions-on-google").DialogflowApp;
const firebase = require("firebase");
const firebaseAdmin = require("firebase-admin");

firebaseAdmin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.cabDemo = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const app = new App({ request, response });

  const BOOK_TAXI = "book.taxi";
  debugger;
  function bookTaxi(app) {
    app.ask("Currently looking for taxis now. Anything else?");
  }

  const actionMap = new Map();    
  actionMap.set(BOOK_TAXI, bookTaxi);
  app.handleRequest(actionMap);
});
```

I have tested this and it deployed correctly yesterday and when I tried to run it this morning it gave me that not responding message. It still deploys correctly but I cannot test it on the simulator.

I have the actions on google project and api.ai projects linked properly so I don't think this is the problem. But I could easily be wrong.

The response from the web simulator is

```
{
  "audioResponse": "//NExAARsE...",
  "conversationToken": "GidzaW11bG...",
  "response": "Cabforce demo isn't responding right now. Try again soon.",
  "visualResponse": {
    "visualElements": []
  }
}
```

and the DEBUG message is:

```
{
  "agentToAssistantDebug": {},
  "assistantToAgentDebug": {}
}
```

This is a duplicate of another question on Stack Overflow => [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47724271/got-the-my-test-app-isnt-responding-right-now-try-again-soon-error-message)

There was **no** solution so I had to repost the question.

I'm receiving the same response and debug message.

All help would be great, thanks !

Comment: thanks for asking a duplicate question, even referring to it....

Comment: It means you have an error in your code somewhere...

Comment: I created another actions on google project and api.ai and linked them and they ran fine. If I test it in the "try it now" section in dialogflow it works fine. I need to use this project as its associated with a billing account

Comment: The problem on this question is it is very generic. And you need to try to make the error radius a bit smaller at first. So there are several questions open. I guess you use Firebase? There i dont know anything about but should be javascript as well. So can you check the log if you get a request or show it some error. And if it got a request can you make sure it sends a response? Can you log that response?

Comment: Apologies I should have given more background. I'm getting this response at the very beginning while trying to start the app. I will edit my original answer for more detail

Comment: Can you include the logs from your firebase function? Anything in the debug tab?

Comment: There are no firebase function logs because the app is not getting that far. But I have added in the response and debug message I am receiving

Comment: Ok so did you know if it reach the firebase function at all? If not check the address url at dialogflow and maybe some gateway settings for the firebase function? If it reach make a log in the beginning which print the request for you.

Comment: Additionally, put some text in the response field in the intent corresponding to the "book.taxi" action in Dialogflow

Comment: Did you find a solution and the root cause?
I have a similar issue: I moved my fully functioning app from one account to another and now it is not working any longer (but still works on the old).

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I may have stumbled on a fix.  It looks like you can now trigger test apps by their name.

1. Go to https://console.actions.google.com
2. Select your app
3. Click Edit under "App Information" (#2)
4. Give the app a name and pronunciation
5. Click "Test Draft" (at the bottom)
6. Invoke the app by name

Hope that works for you.  Seemed to work for me.